# Symfony form validation image required if not already set

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

In Symfony2, I have a form that contains an image upload for a record that was precreated.

When the form renders the first time, image is not set and should be mandatory on form submission. On subsequent form submissions, if the file has already been uploaded and the path stored, then the form submission should pass.

I am unable to figure out how to implement this conditional validation.
My form contains

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builderInterface, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builderInterface, $options);
    $builderInterface
        ->add('logoFile', 'file', array(
            'required' => true,
        ))
    // ...
}
```

However, the required should be enforced only if a specific field on the entity is not populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look to the [Symfony's form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html).

In your case, I think that a thing like :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::/*event*/, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $object = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $form->add('logoFile', 'file', array(
            'required' => !$object || !$object->getLogoFile(),
        ));
    });
}
```

can suit your needs